# Preserving HTML Textbox line break formatting in an Angular Binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to retain the line breaks when binding a textbox to and angular variable?

I have the following:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{invalid: !callerIssue.issuedec.$valid}">
    <label for="issuedec" class="control-label">Issue Description</label>
    <textarea name="issuedec" class="form-control" maxlength="999" rows="7" ng-model="Description" required=""></textarea>
</div>
```

I would like to retain the formatting inputted by the user in the Description variable; i.e line breaks so that it looks like the following:

```
 $scope.Description = "Testing <br/> Data";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did u check: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce ?

Comment: line breaks will be preserved. provide a demo where they aren't. Text line breaks are not `<br>` tags.

Comment: @charlietfl - Thank you for clearing up my misconception. I was unaware that the breaks were not <br> tags. This is helpful!

Comment: @Luca - Thank you for sharing the link. This is my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML tags are not rendered in a standard textarea, If you require HTML in your Description both rendered and the ability to edit with HTML tags you probably need to go down the road of a WYSIWIG Editor

If its just line-breaks you need to worry about, you can use the textnode linebreak of '\n'  in which you don't need to do anything as it will be retained in the string. If your initial data your data contains "br" in the first place you can convert it using the replace below:

```
$scope.Description = "Testing\nData";
```

You can convert 'br' tags to text-node line breaks with something like this:

```
$scope.Description = "Testing <br /> Data";
$scope.Description = $scope.Description.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/bjxjep6v/

Comment: Using a filter might be the proper way to do this, no ?

Comment: @sjm that's not true ... do `date` or `number` filters work on arrays? In other words a filter can take any input

Comment: @charlietfl your right custom filters can be used for non-array's, in this case it probably would only be useful if you were going to reuse the filter elsewhere

Comment: @sjm - Thank you, This helps out a lot. I was operating on the misconception that HTML tags were rendered in the text area. Now if I waned to convert the input to HTML breaks (<br />) I can use something similar to your replace method to change the "\n".

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks in textarea do get preserved when bound to an angularjs variable. Try putting the typed text inside 'pre' tags. Also line breaks are retained when accessed in the controller. Below is an example

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       
        $scope.alertDescription = function(text){
            alert(text);
        }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html data-ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <textarea ng-model="Description" required=""></textarea>
        <pre ng-bind="Description"></pre> 
        <button ng-click="alertDescription(Description)">Alert</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```